# [Swift]I can't get any JSON data from specific URL

Tags: ios, json, swift, url

There are two kinds of URLs

1. http://www.mocky.io/v2/5e91af4b3300008300e9cfd1 (**this is which I made**)
2. http://183.111.148.229/mob_json/mob_json.aspx?nm_sp=UP_MOB_CHECK_LOGIN&param=1000|1000|1 (**I need to get data from this URL**)

**Only number1. URL returns JSON data** even if they have same structure. I couldn't find way to resolve this problem.

this is my network manager code

```
import Foundation
class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {



@Published var posts = [Post]()


func fetchData() {
    if let url = URL(string: "http://www.mocky.io/v2/5e91af4b3300008300e9cfd1") {
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                if let safeData = data {
                    do {
                        let results = try decoder.decode(Results.self, from: safeData)

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.posts = results.Table
                        }   
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

}
}
```

and my post data model

```
import Foundation

struct Results: Decodable {
let Table: [Post]
}

struct Post: Decodable, Identifiable {
var id: String {
    return CD_FIRM
}
let CD_FIRM: String
let NM_FIRM: String
let CD_USER: String
let NM_USER: String
}
```

Can anyone can help me for this problem?
I want to get JSON data from URL number 2.

please help me =)

Comment: Did you just change your current URL with the second URL in your function for test purpose?

Comment: The second URL returns json to me. What does your code receive from the second url?

Comment: The second URL returns json when I input URL to web browser but it returns no data when I use that code. I also changed URL to second URL on my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue with your second url is the pipes `|` at the end. One way to avoid this issue is to use `URLComponents`

So insert this at the start of `fetchData`

```
var urlComponents = URLComponents()
urlComponents.scheme = "http"
urlComponents.host = "183.111.148.229"
urlComponents.path = "/mob_json/mob_json.aspx"
urlComponents.queryItems = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "nm_sp", value: "UP_MOB_CHECK_LOGIN"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "param", value: "1000|1000|1")
]
```

And then get the url from the components

```
if let url =  urlComponents.url {
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    //... same as before
```